# WordPress theme not used after uploading my website on server

Tags: wordpress, themes

I uploaded my WordPress project on my 1&1 server and I'm very disappointed because all my modifications have disappeared. My theme is like Virgin.
What can be wrong? Is there something to save before uploading my files?
Thank you

Comment: You say that all your modifications disappeared. Where did you have your files before? local host or another server? Do you see your theme but without modifications or the default theme?

Comment: My files were in localhost. I see my thème but without any modifications. I checked in my bdd and my articles are here so it's weird

Comment: If you modified your theme using files (I mean rewriting the code) the changes should be there if you uploaded the same. If modifications were in options, you must import the database that stores them.

Answer (score 0):

Theme options - as well as all Wordpress content - is stored in the database, not in theme or static files. When changing servers, you have to moved and correctly configure the database as well as all theme files and uploads.

Read [Moving WordPress « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) and [WordPress Serialized PHP Search Replace Tool](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/)